# Как переименовать пакет?

Tags: android, apk

[image: Как исправить эту ошибку? Приложение делалось на котлине в андройд студио]

Как изменить название пакета? Приложение делалось на котлине в андройд студио

Comment: Так вроде сказано же все ясно в тексте ошибки.

Comment: каком тексте? Какой пакет? Можно подбнобно написать, что нужно исправить?

Comment: Пакет с таким именем уже существует. Переименуйте пакет

Comment: Как исправить ошибку написано 1. в заголовке вопроса, 2. в самом вопросе.

Comment: я не понимаю как изменить название пакета. объясните пожалуйста

Comment: я не понимаю как изменить название пакета. объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Название пакета в манифесте. Записывается туда при компиляции apk

Comment: у приложения есть packagename. если вы сами создавали проект, то на этапе создания вы его задавали. обычно это что-то в стиле `com.my.example`. это имя пакета является уникальным идентификатором. 2ух разных приложений с одним именем быть не может. вот вам надо его сменить. сейчас прилажу инструкцию как сменить имя пакета вручную и полностью самому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ВАРИАНТ №1
ручками изменить имя пакета и все его пути

заходим в strings и изменяем там название приложения. лезем в манифест. там берем packag и переписываем на то, что нам надо. копируем его.

залазим в градле и делаем тоже самое. вылезет окно о синхронизации - ничего не делаем.

открываем в дереве проекта раздел packages. меняем настройки "empty midle packages" (теперь наши пакеты разбиты по папкам). меняем нужные нам части пакетов через рефактор-переименовать.

(НЕ РЕКОМЕНДУЮ ПЕРИМЕНОВЫВАТЬ ОСНОВНОЙ ПАКЕТ!) "com" - выбираем "переименовать current" (если при создании проекта не меняли пакеты).
создаться отдельный пакет, куда все перенесется. после этого пакет, начинающийся с 'com' можно удалить.

для других - "переименовать пакет". когда сменили имена всех пакетов как надо - синхронизируем градл.

готово.

ВАРИАНТ №2
задать имя пакета сборки в градле
этот метод активно применяется когда надо четко разделить билды (например, чтобы на 1 телефоне мог быть установлен И релизный И тестовый билды)
тогда просто не в `defaultConfig` это делается ,а в нужных билдтайпах (или через суффиксы) `applicationIdSuffix`

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.project_name"
    ...
}
```